# In the Trumbowyg editor, what's the difference between the built in undo/redo and the History plugin?

Tags: trumbowyg

I've read the doc and tried the demo, but I can't tell the difference between the built in undo/redo and the History plugin.

The default buttons are:

```
['undo', 'redo'],
```

The plugin buttons are:

```
['historyUndo','historyRedo'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now noticed two differences:

1. With the plugin, the undo/redo buttons are greyed out and unclickable if there are no changes to undo or redo, which is a good improvement. The default undo/redo buttons are not greyed out.
2. With the plugin, it one undo/redo removes or re-adds whole words. The default does a single character or a few characters at a time, seemingly inconsistently.

Curiously, if both the default and plugin buttons are displayed, then clicking either of the default undo/redo buttons will make the plugin's undo button clickable as if there is a change to undo.